# <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h> file not found

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to integrate a facebook login by using Parse. I have followed every step on Facebook ios SDK [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) and Parse SDK [enter link description here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users) setup a Facebook login.

I got 2 issues:

```
<ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h> file not found
Failed to import bridging header '-file path-'
```

I realized that in the 'parse-library-1.7.5' fold, there are 2 framework, one is *'ParseFacebookUtils.framework'*, another is '*ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework'*. Followed the step, I only import '**ParseFacebookUtils.framework**' into the project navigator.

bridge header saved under project file and I have set up ->target->build settings->install object-c compatibility header to be YES.

Dose anyone help for these 2 issues? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above got me pointed in the right direction but for me the error was a bit different referring to the build module could not be found for ParseFacebookUtilsV4. That led me to cocoa pods where I confirmed the pod file (which also doesnt support ,:head to get the most current version).

Then did the following steps most probably already know: 
 1) Terminal -> cd "/somepath/wherethe/workspaceis/" 
 2) Confirmed my pod file open -a Xcode podfile (assuming the pod file exists and has been initiated). 
 3) Added or confirmed its typed exactly as is shown on CocaPods: pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4' 
 4) Terminal -> pod install

This got the pod file installed and added to the project and shows up in the project targets in Xcode.

Unfortunately this created a new problem :-[, however I did a pod update and the Bolts pod was updated to the required 1.2.2 and all subsequent pods installed and updated correctly.

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Bolts/Tasks (= 1.2.1)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `Bolts/Tasks (>= 1.2.2)` required by `Parse (HEAD based on 1.8.5)`

Hope this helps with the immediate topic at least.

Link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4

Answer (score 2):

I think you should import both frameworks as I did and I have no problem. Sometimes the doc is just not quite up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks. I figure out that I only need import V4 version by using beta xcode 7

Comment: I think the key is that you have imported v4 version. Using beta xcode7 shouldn't play a big part. Great anyway you solved it! You have my up vote:)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I realized it was because when I copied the ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework from the unzipped Parse SDK folder, I did not select "Copy items if needed", and so the file wasn't copied, but only a reference to it seemed to have been created, that is the reason the   file was not found.

I am adding a snapshot of the selection i made when copying the file to the project: [image]